# How can I run a function several times using Python's multiprocessing module?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have the following function that simulates a system of chemical reactions over time:

```
def gillespie_tau_leaping(propensity_calc, popul_num, LHS, stoch_rate, popul_num_all, tao_all, rxn_vector, tao, epsi): 
    t = simulation_timer()
    t.start()
    leap_counter = 0
    while tao < tmax:
        propensity = propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate) # array that contains the probability of each reaction firing --> calculated in a function called propensity_calc
        a0 = (sum(propensity))
        if a0 == 0.0:
            break
        if popul_num.any() < 0:  # popul_num an array that contains the discrete number of molecules for each reactant in the system.
            break   
        b = update_array(popul_num, stoch_rate)  # A derivative used to calculate delta_t
        delta_t = time_step_calc(propensity_calc, state_change_array, b, epsi) # delta_t = the time increment to increase the system by after each iteration
        lam = (propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)*delta_t) # probability of a reaction firing in the time period delta_t
        rxn_vector = np.random.poisson(lam) 
        if tao + delta_t > tmax: # tao = current time of system, tmax = maximum simulation time allowed
            break
        if delta_t >= 1/a0:
            tao += delta_t 
            for j in range(len(rxn_vector)):
                state_change_lambda = np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j])*rxn_vector[j]) 
                popul_num = popul_num + state_change_lambda
            leap_counter += 1 
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)
            tao_all.append(tao)  
        else: 
            next_t = np.random.exponential(1/a0)
            rxn_probability = propensity / a0   
            num_rxn = np.arange(rxn_probability.size)       
            if tao + next_t > tmax:      
                tao = tmax
                break
            j = stats.rv_discrete(values=(num_rxn, rxn_probability)).rvs() 
            tao = tao + next_t
            popul_num = popul_num + np.squeeze(np.asarray(state_change_array[j]))  
            popul_num_all.append(popul_num)   
            tao_all.append(tao)  
    print("Molecule numbers:\n", popul_num)
    print("Time of final simulation:\n", tao)
    print("Number of reactions:\n", len(tao_all))
    print("leap counter:\n", leap_counter)
    t.stop()
    return popul_num_all.append(popul_num), tao_all.append(tao)
```

Other inputs, `LHS` an array of the ratios between reactants of each reaction, `stoch_rate` the rate of each reaction in the system, `tao_all` an array used to store all the consecutive values of tao (used for plotting) `popul_num_all` same as `tao_all` but for the molecule numbers.

I then use the following code to plot the output:

```
for i, label in enumerate(['Enzyme', 'Substrate', 'Enzyme-Substrate complex', 'Product']):
    plt.plot(tao_all, popul_num_all[:, i], label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I need to run this function multiple times using pythons `multiprocessing` library and plot the graph the same number of times.

I've read the `multiprocessing` docs for the `processing` and `pool` classes but firstly can't decided which is more appropriate to use, and secondly I cant get either to work, with out running into:

`Timeouterrors`

`AttributeErrors` on the line `popul_num_all.append(popul_num)` (which are only thrown during parallel processing)

Or the graph thats being plotted being incorrect.

Cheers